# cakephp adding record with some parameters fixed

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm sure this sort of problem must be common in cakephp (which I've recently started using), but I haven't managed to find a clear answer.

In my database I have, among others, tables called customers and contacts, in a one-to-many relationship (Customer hasMany Contact; Contact belongsTo Customer). When I add a record to the contacts table (/contacts/add), I can choose the customer (customer_id) from a select box containing all the customers in the database. How can I set it up so that I can choose the customer first (/customers/view/6), then add a contact for that specific customer (e.g. /contacts/add/6); and then remove the select box from the "add contact" form (maybe replacing it with a hidden customer_id field)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but I think the best is using the [named parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/view/541/Named-parameters).

Essentially, in your views/customers/view.ctp, you add a customer_id to the contacts/add link:

```
$html->link(__('Add contact', true), array('controller' => 'contacts', 'action' => 'add', 'customer_id' => $customer['Customer']['id']));
```

and in your views/contacts/add.ctp you check for the named parameter and use a hidden field:

```
if (isset($this->params['named']['customer_id'])) {
    echo $form->input('customer_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $this->params['named']['customer_id']));
} else {
    echo $form->input('customer_id');
}
```

or a select with the right customer already selected:

```
echo $form->input('customer_id', array('selected' => @$this->params['named']['customer_id']));
```

Comment: Neat way of getting rid of unset array key :)

Comment: Finally found an answer! =DDD Great job!

Answer (score 1):

However that is not a solution when you want to secure the field information. It still could be being received with a different value. How about a way to set it in the controller before saving??

Answer (score 1):

To answer the security problem with using hidden fields, you can use cake's Security component which locks them to prevent tampering. It works simply by adding it out of the box.