# CakePHP table primary key is missing in add function

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, primary-key

I have post and comment tables and I should give the option for the user to add new comments.
While adding new comments the user should have the option to select the post from the list box and add comments for that.

But in CakePHP the primary key fields are hidden in view by default. How can I enable that in the add form?

I am using CakePHP2.0 version

Comment: this answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034343/cakephp-adding-record-with-some-parameters-fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Treelist to select the post and comment:
You can refer to: http://bvirtual.nl/2009/11/easy-trees-with-tree-behavior-in.html.